# Applying string operations to pandas data frame

Tags: python, string, pandas

There are similar answers but I could not apply it to my own case
I wanna get rid of forbidden characters for Windows directory names in my pandas dataframe. I tried to use something like:

```
df1['item_name'] =  "".join(x for x in df1['item_name'].rstrip() if x.isalnum() or x in [" ", "-", "_"]) if df1['item_name'] else ""
```

Assume I have a dataframe like this

```
 item_name
0  st*back
1  yhh?\xx
2  adfg%s
3  ghytt&{23
4  ghh_h
```

I want to get:

```
   item_name
0  stback
1  yhhxx
2  adfgs
3  ghytt23
4  ghh_h
```

How I could achieve this?
Note: I scraped data from internet earlier, and used the following code for the older version

```
item_name = "".join(x for x in item_name.text.rstrip() if x.isalnum() or x in [" ", "-", "_"]) if item_name else ""
```

Now, I have new observations for the same items and I want to merge them with older observations. But I forgot to use the same method when I rescraped

Comment: `df.item_name = df.item_name.apply(lambda x: x.replace("\s|-|_", "")`

Comment: no but I wanna keep "_" and "-"  just I wanna get rid of the items that forbidden for Windows directory.

Comment: should have been `re.sub` anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could summarize the condition as a negative character class, and use `str.replace` to remove them, here `\w` stands for word characters `alnum + _`, `\s` stands for space and `-` is literal dash. With `^` in the character class, `[^\w\s-]` matches any character that is not alpha numeric, nor `[" ", "-", "_"]`, then you can use `replace` method to remove them:

```
df.item_name.str.replace("[^\w\s-]", "")

#0     stback
#1      yhhxx
#2      adfgs
#3    ghytt23
#4      ghh_h
#Name: item_name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Sorry I edited my question, it would achieve the same that I did before?

Comment: It should. as stated in the answer, this pattern removes characters that are not `[a-zA-Z0-9, _, -, " "]`.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
import re
df.item_name.apply(lambda x: re.sub('\W+', '', x))

0     stback
1      yhhxx
2      adfgs
3    ghytt23
4      ghh_h
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a properly escaped list of characters

```
lst = ['\\\\', '\*', '\?', '%', '&', '\{']
df.replace(lst, '', regex=True)

  item_name
0    stback
1     yhhxx
2     adfgs
3   ghytt23
4     ghh_h
```